# pyqt меню правой кнопкой по нажатию на qlabel

Tags: python, gui, menu, pyqt

Доброго времени суток всем, пытаюсь реализовать отображение контекстного меню по нажатию на Qlabel.
Вот код:

```
class streamWidgetOne(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    settingsStream = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(streamWidgetOne, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)

    def openMenu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        addDes = QtWidgets.QAction('test', menu)
        addDes.triggered.connect(self.start_script)
        menu.addAction(addDes)
        menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal())

    def start_script(self):
        self.settingsStream.emit()
```

Именно необходимо реализовать это в QLabel, так как туда выводится изображение с камеры, а из меню хочу управлять уже потоком. Вообще возможно отображать меню по нажатию правой кнопкой на QLabel? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да это возможно. Для этого необходимо просто переопределить метод `contextMenuEvent` и передать координаты `event.pos` по которым будет выведено меню.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

class MenuLabel(Qt.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = Qt.QMenu(self)
        action = menu.addAction("Action")
        result = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == result:
            print("Action")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    label = MenuLabel("Label with menu")
    label.show()
    app.exec_()
```